# Clarification on an integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image: math]

How did we get from line 2 to line 3?? I've been stuck on this for an eternity... Thank you!

Comment: using the derivation law of variable upper limit function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the fundamental theorem of integral calculus: under suitable hypotheses,

$$\frac{d}{dy}\int_0^yf(u)du=f(y)\;.$$

Take $f(u)=\dfrac{\sin u}u$ and $y=x^2$, and let

$$g(y)=\int_0^yf(u)du\;;$$

then by the chain rule we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}g(y)=\frac{d}{dy}g(y)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=2xf(x^2)=\frac{2x\sin x^2}{x^2}\;.$$